# Filtering the dataframe with conditions in Pandas and reaching the rest of the dataframe (.loc)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I would like to create another dataframe with a condition from one column.
This method I am trying is working:

```
   Y = X.loc[(X['ColumnnA'] == "22.33.44.55")
                                                  | (X['ColumnnA'] == "12.12.32.44") 
                                                  | (X['ColumnnA'] == "45.142.22.22") 
                                                  | (X['ColumnnA'] == "55.197.55.8") 
                                                  | (X['ColumnnA'] == "44.44.211.254") 
                                                  | (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.44.234.83") 
                                                  | (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.33.221.240") 
                                                  | (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.33.33.1") 
                                                 ]
```

But with .loc function, I cannot use this:

```
restdataframe = X[~Y]
Y=X[Y]
```

How can I use this with .loc?

Strange but I was using the below method last week and it was working for another dataframe, with the same columns now this runs but it provides me a wrong "shape". With .loc, it gives a correct answer.  I want to understand what I am doing wrong with below code? Why it does not work properly?

```
Y = (X['ColumnnA'] == "22.33.44.55")
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "12.12.32.44") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "45.142.22.22") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "55.197.55.8") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "44.44.211.254") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.44.234.83") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.33.221.240") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.33.33.1")
```

Note: I run it in one line because of the invalid syntax

Example of X:
[image]

Comment: If someone can just help me to reach the rest of dataframe after the filtering with .loc, that is also great for me.

Comment: Can you please provide part of `X`?

Comment: X has 14 columns, 111k rows. ColumnnA is the IP address.

Comment: I mean please provide the first 10 rows of your actual data frame as code. I cannot reproduce your issue with my pseudo data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code to reproduce you X dataframe it is hard to say for sure, but you probably want to use:

```
restdataframe = X[X!=Y]
Y = X[X==Y]
```

When you use  `Y = X.loc[.....]` you dont create a mask but select the values from X which meet you conditions. Therefore you have to recreate a mask to make your selection from X. You can do this by comparing where X and Y are/arent the same.

Alternatively you can create Y as a mask:

```
Y = ((X['ColumnnA'] == "22.33.44.55")
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "12.12.32.44") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "45.142.22.22") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "55.197.55.8") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "44.44.211.254") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.44.234.83") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.33.221.240") 
| (X['ColumnnA'] == "33.33.33.1"))
```

then run your original:

```
restdataframe = X[~Y]
Y=X[Y]
```